# Is there a way to delete a message from pubsub message store?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using GCP Pubsub to send and receive JSON data, Pubsub has a feature to retain a message from a time period of 10 minutes up to 7 days and not less than 10 minutes (according to the official documentation). Is there any way to delete a pulled message from Pubsub? If not, then why do we say that Pubsub is a "Queuing technique" when we willingly cannot delete a message from a message store which violates a basic queue property?

I am using python Pubsub client library for the scripting purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Messages are retained by Google Cloud Pub/Sub under two conditions:

1. The message has not yet been acknowledged for a subscription and the retention duration has not passed.
2. [retainAckedMessages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/create#body.request_body.FIELDS.retain_acked_messages) is enabled and the retention duration has not passed.

Once you have received a message and called [ack](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/pubsub/subscriber/api/message.html#google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.message.Message.ack) on it within the ack deadline, the message will no longer be redelivered for that subscription (other than duplicates that can happen given that Pub/Sub has at-least-once delivery semantics).

Comment: So, if I acknowledge the message in the pubsub, then the message will vanish from pubsub. Thanks, my doubt is clear now.

Answer (score 15):

If needed, you can also perform a purge inside the subscriber section and that will acknowledge all of the message currently waiting inside the store for that specific subscriber.

Go to subscriptions -> *specific subscriber* -> purge messages